# Array data in localStorage, resets after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, local-storage

Im working on page where I need to save object data to the localStorage, its working fine, but when I refresh the page and add again, all the data is remove.

what I want is prevent the reseting of array list.

hope you understand me.

thanks.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/RMymvx)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var films = [];
  
  $('button').click(function(){
      
     var film = {
              'id': 4,
              'title':'John Wick',
              'Genre':'Action'
             };
   films.push(film);
   localStorage.setItem("films", JSON.stringify(films));

   var movies = localStorage.getItem("films");
   movies     = JSON.parse(movies);

   console.log(movies);

  });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the existing `localStorage.films`, if it exists, and put it into the `films` variable at the beginning.

```
const films = JSON.parse(localStorage.films || '[]');
```

Comment: (Probably worth sticking with ES5 when the OP does, what with IE11 being the new IE6.)

Comment: sir, I got error ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `films' before initialization

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla replace your `var films` line with mine. If you've already done that, then the problem is elsewhere - maybe you ran something before `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 2):

you need to storage localStorage data on page reload in films.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = localStorage.getItem("films");
    var films = data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];

    $('button').click(function(){

            var film = {
              'id': 4,
              'title':'John Wick',
              'Genre':'Action'
             };
        films.push(film);
        localStorage.setItem("films", JSON.stringify(films));

        var movies = localStorage.getItem("films");
        movies = JSON.parse(movies);

        console.log(movies);

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Before setting the value you need to get the existing value and then concate new value with the existing value and set it to local storage.

```
var movies = localStorage.getItem("films");
movies = JSON.parse(movies || '[]');
films.concat(movies);
localStorage.setItem("films", JSON.stringify(films));
```